# A POST request caused my site URL changed with the POST params.

Tags: reactjs, post, react-redux

I am doing a POST request to auth api with a username and password and expecting a token in the response.

```
fetch('https://auth.entranceplus.in/auth', {
                credentials: 'omit',
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "username": this.userName.value,
                    "password": this.password.value
                }),
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Data-Type': "json"
                })
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json();
                } else if (response.status === 503) {
                    this.setErrorMessage('Failed to check-out license');
                } else {
                    this.setErrorMessage('Incorrect Username or Password');
                }
            }.bind(this)).then(json => {
                localStorage.setItem('username', this.userName.value);
                localStorage.setItem('accesstoken', json.access_token);
            });
```

As you can see in the image Request URL is http://localhost:3000/?username=dfbfdjhgfk&password=76895jfjg

[image]

My question is why the request not getting posted to https://auth.entranceplus.in/auth

Comment: I’m pretty sure there’s something wrong outside this. Remove the whole fetch call and see what happens. I assume it will still do this.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks for the clue. I figured out the issue.